# Multiple Python Inheritance with abstract class calls __new__ method wrong number of arguments

Tags: python

I have the following situation:

```
class AbstractSpeaker(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def say_hello(self)->None:
         pass

    """... other abstract and maybe even concrete methods ..."""

class BasicGreeter:
  """implements a basic say_hello method so that Speakers
  don't need to implement it"""
  def __new__(cls):
      r=object.__new__(cls)
      r._language=Language.English #assume that Language is an appropriate Enum
      return r

 @property
 def language(self)->Language: 
    return self._language

 @language.setter
 def language(self, newLanguage:Language):
    self._language=newLanguage

 def say_hello(self)->None:
    if self.language is Language.English:
       print("Hello")
    elif self.language is Language.German:
       print("Hallo")
    elif self.language is Language.Italian:
      print("Ciao")
    else:
      print("Hi")

class Person(BasicGreeter, AbstractSpeaker):
    def __init__(self, name):
       self.name=name
    """goes on to implement everything AbstractSpeaker speaker commands but should
       use the say_hello method from BasicGreeter, who should also hold the language
       information.
    """
```

But when I want to generate a new Person I get an TypeError:

```
>>> peter=Person('Peter')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
peter=Person('Peter')
TypeError: __new__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Now I get that it has something to do with the fact that I have implemented a **new** method in BasicGreeter because when I rewrite BasicGreeter to use an **init** method instead of the **new**-method and then explicitly call super.**init**() in the Person's init it works. But I wanted to know if there is any way to do this with the **new** method as having to invoke super.**init**() in every Speakers init can be a bug source if ever forgotten. Any ideas, can this (a class implementing basic compliance in some areas for an abstract class so that children of that abstract class don't need to implement the same code) be done? I know that I could always go the 3 generation route making the BasicGreeter an abstract class, but I think that is more elegant way as it allows BasicGreeter to be used for other families f.e. I might have a class Robot with a subclass FriendlyRobot that could also make use of inheriting from BasicGreeter but a Robot is not necessarily a speaker and vice versa.

Comment: This shouldn't be in `__new__`. I really couldn't understand why you don't use `__init__`...

Comment: When using `super`, you need to keep the signature of the overridden methods *compatible* with what they override. If your class *adds* a parameter, it needs to ensure that the argument is passed to `super`, because *some* ancestor will not be expecting it.

Comment: @Tomerikoo because __init__ needs to be called extra, new is called automatically.

Comment: But calling `super` inside `__init__` is standard, idiomatic way of doing inheritance. Using `__new__` just to bypass that is unidiomatic. What's wrong with calling `super`? Anyway, the error is pretty clear about it: your `__new__` only takes the class but you pass it extra arguments

Comment: In this case I would like to avoid it in Person as BasicGreeter is not a prime ancestor of Person, more like a distance relative who left an useful heritage in this case the say_hello function and the language property. But fine I changed the new method of BasicGreeter to use a *args argument and super instead of object and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error gives you the solution, simply let the **new** method to take the arguments even if you don't use them:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Language():
    English = 'english'

class AbstractSpeaker(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def say_hello(self)->None:
         pass

    """... other abstract and maybe even concrete methods ..."""

class BasicGreeter:
    """implements a basic say_hello method so that Speakers don't need to implement it"""
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):   # Fix to your code
        # print(args,kwargs)
        r=object.__new__(cls)
        r._language=Language.English 
        return r
    @property
    def language(self)->Language: 
        return self._language

    @language.setter
    def language(self, newLanguage:Language):
        self._language=newLanguage

    def say_hello(self)->None:
        if self.language is Language.English:
            print("Hello")
        elif self.language is Language.German:
            print("Hallo")
        elif self.language is Language.Italian:
            print("Ciao")
        else:
            print("Hi")

class Person(BasicGreeter, AbstractSpeaker):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        
    """goes on to implement everything AbstractSpeaker speaker commands but should
       use the say_hello method from BasicGreeter, who should also hold the language
       information.
    """
```

This piece of code works, said that, I'm not sure in what you need such a structure inside **new**, is a way of making a singleton?

Comment: No it was just so a pattern that came up in my project. I works I just didn't realized that all init parameters would given to the new method of the parent. Any way to avoid that other than an explicit super call?

Comment: Don't use `object`; use `super`. If `BasicGreeter` appears immediately before `object` in the MRO, it does the same thing. If it does *not*, then `object.__new__` gets called prematurely, and since `object.__new__` does not use `super`, no other class's `__new__` method can be called.

Comment: Yes, it is technically possible, you can use a metaclass (preferred) or even maybe class decorator, anyway, normally the "super" call would be the right way to go here.